# How long can the Enterprise's shields hold?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The Enterprise is under attack from a Romulan Bird of Prey that is firing phasers which do (say: 33.333) units of damage per minute.

The Enterprise's shields are rated to resist say (100) units of damage before being completely depleted.

However, as the shields are depleted, the resistance drops proportionally: At 100% they absorb 100% of damage, while at 75% they absorb 75% of damage where the remaining (25%) damage is sustained by the Enterprise's hull.

so a one-minute attack which does 33.333 units of damage would reduce the shields from 100% to 75% (absorbing 25 damage), and the hull will sustain the remaining 8.333 damage.

(I think that's right, anyway.)

For the next shot, the shields will start at 75%, meaning greater damage to the hull, but how much?

More importantly, how would I create a general formula which can calculate hull damage for any shield rating/level and any attack power?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand the initial condition.  It seems like the shields start at $100\%$ efficiency, so they would never be depleted.  I think you need to start them at something close to $100\%$, but not exactly.

If we let $y(t)$ be the resistance of the shields at time $t$, where $0\leq y(t)\leq 1$ then the equation is $$y'= -k(1-y)\tag1$$ where $k$ represents the power of the phasers.  In the example, $k=\frac13.$  When $y=\frac34$, we get $$y'=-\frac13\left(1-\frac34\right)=-\frac1{12},$$ so that the resistance decreases by $\frac1{12},$ as in the example.

The general solution to $(1)$ is $$y=ae^{kt}+1,\tag2$$ where $a$ is a constant to be determined from the initial condition.  That is, $a=1-y(0)$.  If we set $y(0)=1$ as you say, then of course, $a=0$, and the shields stay at full resistance always.

If the shields start at $99.99\%$ efficiency, then we get $$y(t)=1-.0001e^{t/3}$$ when $k=\frac13.$

Comment: I suppose my thought was that the shield resistance is equal to the shield level at every instant, so for the first quantum of time, the shield absorbs all damage, but is itself damaged accordingly, so the next moment, with the shield being slightly depleted, so too the damage absorbed is reduced.

Comment: @ridthyself That's fine, but for the mathematical model, I think you have to make some adjustment, as suggested in my answer.